# Get BottomSheetBehaviour from BottomSheetDialog

Tags: android, android-layout, grid-layout, bottom-sheet

This is my layout for BottomSheetDialog. I've a grid layout inside as well. That grid layout's scrolling is not proper. I mean it scrolls only in expanded state of BottomSheetDialog.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/view_padding_medium"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_image"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_image"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_padding_medium"
            android:text="@string/smart_action_share"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
             />
    </LinearLayout>



    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="3"
        >

    </GridView>


</LinearLayout>
```

This is the way i'm creating a bottom sheet dialog:

```
BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) Constants.getContext()).getLayoutInflater();

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_share1, null);

        bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(view);

    final GridView grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView11);

    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter (context);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);

    bottomSheetDialog.show();
```

How can the behaviour of dialog be accessed so that i can fix the grid layout scrolls or is there any other way of fixing that?

Just to make everything clear:
Grid view scroll should be enabled everytime irrespective of the state of bottom sheet.

Comment: make grid view not scrollable.

Comment: the whole point is to enable grid view scroll everytime irrespective of the state of bottom sheet.

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar Any suggestions??

Comment: @Div_D, Referring to your comment in the Answer below, you manage to fix it. So, by using RecyclerView and GridLayoutManager instead of GridView, scroll/slide behavior prioritize the RecyclerView instead of the BottomSheetDialog?

Comment: @Div_D, Cool! It's working. You should post your answer here and it should be the accepted answer. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Grid view scroll should be enabled everytime irrespective of the state
>   of bottom sheet.

I don't think you should do this because the BottomSheet height should match the content's height.

This means that if the content is scrollable and exceeds the parent's height, scroll will only work if the BottomSheet is expanded because of the default behavior, which makes sense.

To have access to the behavior, you can do:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_share1, null);
bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(view);

BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) view.getParent());
```

And then, to customize the behavior on state different from expanded:

```
behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet,
            @BottomSheetBehavior.State int newState) {
        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
            dismiss();
        }else{
            if (newState != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                // Implement your logic here
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset){

    }
};
```

Comment: can i do something to set the grid layout position to 0 everytime the bottomsheet is not in expanded state? The problem is i've more elements in gridlayout than can fit in one full screen. If i scroll down when the bottomsheet is in expanded state and then drag the bottomsheet to non collapsed state, the top elements are partially hidden because of the scroll and since i can't scroll up now, i've to move back to the expanded state to scroll up so that the top elements are also visible.

Comment: i got rid of the problem by using a RecyclerView with Grid Layout Manager instead of a Grid Layout.

Comment: You could use a custom BottomSheetCallback to customize that behavior.

I'll edit the original answer with an example.

Comment: My view has no coordinator layout. BottomSheetBehaviour crashes in such a case.

Comment: Your view doesn't need a CoordinatorLayout because BottomSheetDialog inflates one for you. Your view is wrapped inside one.
Take a look at the method:
`wrapInBottomSheet(int layoutResId, View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)`

Answer (score -1):

You can do (Kotlin):

```
    val params = ((view.parent as View).layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)
    val behavior = params.behavior

    if (behavior is BottomSheetBehavior) {
        behavior.doStuff()
    }
```